# Overloading woocommerce/wordpress methods (instead of overriding template files)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, overloading

I've been trying to find an answer to this (seemingly easy) question. It's about overloading methods in Wordpress plugins in general and WooCommerce specifically.

I'm setting up a Woocommerce site and know how to override template files, but my problem is this.

I don't like the output of the get_order_item_totals() (WC_Order) - I want the VAT to be visible on its own row even though I show prices including VAT in cart/checkout. Since the method gets called at several places it seems a little bit tedious and 'non-DRY' to override the template files on all these places (emails/customer-completed-order.php and order/order-details.php and so on).

I also don't want to change the core files since I know the shit will hit the fan when I upgrade the system and forgotten that I made the changes.

Is there a way to overload (for example) the order->get_order_item_totals() from the theme?

Help would be much appreciated
Joakim Carlsten

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I solved it by using the filter that get_order_item_totals calls in the end. There I changed the $totals_rows array.

:)